# What code should be written for the joystick?

Tags: godot4

Joystick code (working):

```
@tool
extends TouchScreenButton

@export_range(0.0,1.0) var inner_opacity : float = 0.9
@export_range(0.0,1.0) var outer_opacity : float = 0.5

var direction : Vector2 = Vector2(0,0)
var strength : float = 0.0
var was_pressed : bool = false
var button_index : int = -1
var held : bool = false

@onready var half_width := self.texture_normal.get_width()/2
@onready var half_height := self.texture_normal.get_height()/2
@onready var inner_joystick_image : Sprite2D = $inner
@onready var radius :float = 75.0


signal joystick_input
signal joystick_released

func _ready():
    inner_joystick_image.position = Vector2(half_width,half_height)
    self_modulate = Color(1,1,1,outer_opacity)  
    $inner.modulate = Color(1,1,1,inner_opacity)
    $inner.position = Vector2(half_width,half_height)
    if shape is CircleShape2D:
        radius = shape.radius


func _input(event):
    if not event is InputEventScreenTouch and not event is InputEventScreenDrag: # Not a touch
        return

    if button_index != -1 and button_index != event.index: # No index, or index 
        return
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch and event.pressed == false:
        inner_joystick_image.global_position = global_position + Vector2(half_width,half_height)
        button_index = -1
        emit_signal("joystick_input", 0, Vector2(0,0), 0)
        emit_signal("joystick_released")
        held = false
        return
    if is_pressed(): # Button still in pressed state
        strength = event.position.distance_to(global_position+Vector2(half_width,half_height))
        if strength <= radius:
            button_index = event.index
        if button_index != event.index:
            return
        strength = smoothstep(0,radius,strength)
        direction = event.position.direction_to(global_position+Vector2(half_width,half_height)) * -1
        inner_joystick_image.global_position = clamp_to_circle(global_position+Vector2(half_width,half_height), radius, event.position)
        get_viewport().set_input_as_handled()
        held = true


func clamp_to_circle(point: Vector2, radius: float, value: Vector2) -> Vector2:
    var direction = value - point
    if direction.length_squared() > radius * radius:
        direction = direction.normalized() * radius
    return point + direction
    
func _process(delta):
    if held:
        emit_signal("joystick_input", strength, direction, delta)
```

Sprite code (not working)

```
extends Sprite2D


@export var direction : Vector2 = Vector2()
var speed = 200



func _ready():
    pass

func _process(delta):

        if direction == Vector2(1, 0):
            position.x += speed * delta
        elif direction == Vector2(-1, 0):
            position.x -= speed * delta
        elif direction == Vector2(0, 1):
            position.y += speed * delta
        elif direction == Vector2(0, -1):
            position.y -= speed * delta
```

Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me

Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me
Please help me

Comment: How are you setting the direction of the Sprite2D?

Comment: Why would you create 4 if branches for updating the position of the sprite if you can do simple vector math: position += direction * speed * delta ???

Comment: @Bgie not working

Comment: @Theraot I did not make any settings (the code is not mine)

Comment: If you never set the `direction` of the `Sprite2D` it will always be `Vector2()`, and never `Vector2(1, 0)` or `Vector2(-1, 0)` or `Vector2(0, 1)` or `Vector2(0, -1)`. So the execution flow will never enter where you set `position`. So it does not move.